Setting up OAuth authentication for the Google Vision API
I'm trying to use the Google Vision API and finding the OAuth setup to be really confusing.
This is for a desktop app that I'm creating for my own use. It won't be deployed.
I'd like to minimize the number of web browser authentications, or even avoid them if possible.
I've created a Google service account for this, but it seems these do not issue refresh tokens.
Google's own documentation is really confusing, as there seem to be a bunch of other factors in addition to OAuth.
Is there a better way to approach this? Should I not use a service account? Any suggestions?
I have it sort of working, but am constantly asked to authenticate. Google keeps sending me "Security alert" emails that access was granted. I don't seem to be getting a refresh token.

If you have gcloud installed the best approach to use user credentials and ADC see the Auth to Vision doc. Without gcloud unless you can use Workload Identity Federation, you can use a Service Account. How are you using the API? Are you (hopefully) using one of Google's SDKs?

Thanks for your comment. I don't have gcloud installed and I don't know what Workload Identity Federation is about. Presumably I don't have it. I just have a vanilla google account. I'm using the API via REST requests. It's all working for me now, except for authentication, which is just endlessly asking me to prove that I'm me.
If possible, I would like to avoid setting/installing up more fragile junk or environment variables on my workstation.

Please update your question to include your code. Otherwise it's difficult to provide further help. I sense your frustration but I can assure you that Google's services and SDKs are robust and we will be able to get this to work without issue. I encourage you to consider using one of Google's SDKs for Vision API client library

Thanks for kindly replying. I'm not using an SDK, nor a common language, so posting the code is not going to help. No doubt the cloud services are all working fine and it's pilot error. I guess my question is more about how Google cloud works with OAuth. I'm using a service account, ergo I don't get a refresh token and it seems I need to completely re-authenticate every 3000 seconds or somesuch — is that correct? Is there a guide to just use my regular account, get refresh tokens, and without installing more stuff on my workstation (e.g., gcloud)? Thanks!

Google's documentation is comprehensive OAuth for Server to Server using Service Accounts. You're correct that there's no refresh token (it's two-legged OAuth) but you must still refresh the access token every 3600s. Good luck

I have seen that page, but it is only about service accounts. My question is: how can I do this without a service account, so I can get a refresh token? Is there a way to just send HTTP requests and get a refresh token? My app is working, but I am being continually asked to reauthorize, and it's really tiresome. Basically, I want to authorize once and then never have to do that again. This whole endless dance of "are you really still you?" is just too much.

There is no secure OAuth flow that permits issuing a token once. The SDKs insulate you from this by performing the refresh for you. If you go it alone, you have to do this for yourself. There's a parallel flow that uses 3-legged OAuth for web applications but this is generally only required when user-specific data is being accessed (e.g. a Gmail account) and not when using general-purposes services such as Vision. Good luck!

I wrote an article to show you how that uses curl and obtains a refresh token. You can adapt that to any language you are using. https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-refresh-access-token/ However, there are other methods used with devices (smart televisions) where you only need to authenticate once in a while (weekly). Your post does not include details on what you are using, so we must guess. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device

Thank you both. I finally figured it out. OAuth takes time to learn !
Switching from a service to a regular acct allowed me to use refresh tokens and the requests to validate identity requests are no longer quasi-constant. Whew.
